# Shell Script - "split" em for

Tags: shell-script, shell

Fiz uma query que imputa o resultado em um arquivo `.txt` neste molde:

```
-----id--------action    
H000tg6b JOB
H000oi8a JOB
H00067w JOB
```

Preciso fazer um `for` para percorrer esse arquivo e utilizar as duas informações.

A primeira é para usar em uma operação a segunda é para verificar se a action em questão é igual a `JOB`, se for, executa um comando e se não for, executa outro.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer é a separação entre esses dois atributos ao percorrer o `.txt`.

Pensei em utilizar o awk afim de ter acesso aos dois atributos em questão mas não consegui dar continuidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você pode usar `tail` para ignorar a primeira linha (o cabeçalho). Usando o parâmetro `-n +X`, sendo `X` a linha a partir da qual você quer considerar. Considerando que o arquivo é:

```
-----id--------action
H000tg6b JOB
H000oi8a JOB
H00067w JOB
```

Se eu fizer:

```
tail -n +2 arq.txt
```

A saída é:

```
H000tg6b JOB
H000oi8a JOB
H00067w JOB
```

Agora é só passar esta saída para o `awk` e testar se o segundo campo é `"JOB"`:

```
tail -n +2 arq.txt | awk '{if ($2 == "JOB") { system("ls") } }'
```

No exemplo acima, estou chamando o comando `ls`, mas você pode trocar pelo que precisar.

---

Usar `system` pode ser meio inconveniente se você quer chamar vários comandos. Sendo assim, uma outra alternativa é criar um arquivo de script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' # o for considera uma linha inteira a cada iteração
for i in `tail -n +2 arq.txt | awk '{ print $1 " " $2 }'`
do
    primeiro=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d' '`
    segundo=`echo $i | cut -f2 -d' '`
    if [ "$segundo" = "JOB" ]; then
        echo "primeiro campo=$primeiro"
        # coloque quantos comandos precisar aqui
    fi
done
```

Como neste exemplo todas as linhas tem "JOB" no segundo campo, a saída do script será:

```
primeiro campo=H000tg6b
primeiro campo=H000oi8a
primeiro campo=H00067w
```

Eu usei `awk` porque ele já separa por vários espaços, enquanto o `cut` só aceita um espaço como separador (embora [seja possível contornar isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476712)). Por isso uso o `awk` para formatar cada linha com os campos separados por um espaço, e depois uso o `cut` para pegar cada campo individualmente.

---

Se o arquivo não tiver cabeçalho e quiser pegar todas as linhas, troque a linha do `for` para:

```
for i in `awk '{ print $1 " " $2 }' arq.txt`
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar `read` (considerando um arquivo sem a primeira linha do cabeçalho). A vantagem é que não precisa usar `cut` para quebrar a linha em duas variáveis, você pode passá-las diretamente após o `read`:

```
#!/bin/bash

(while read primeiro segundo
 do
    if [ "$segundo" = "JOB" ]; then
        echo "primeiro campo=$primeiro"
        # coloque todos os comandos que precisar
    fi
 done ) < <(cat arq.txt)
```

Comment: O " ------id----- action" foi só para representar que são dois parâmetros, ignore-os, o .txt original é só as informações. Neste caso eu usaria apenas o for e o awk para coletar os dois parâmetros? Poderia dar um exemplo neste caso?

Comment: @PedroBaraldini Sim, faça apenas `awk '{ print $1 " " $2 }' arquivo` dentro do `for`. Adicionei isso na resposta

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado pela ajuda!